# Difficulty splitting array and returning a value from within it; Javascript

Tags: function, javascript

I have got an array that consists of strings. I have made a function that searches the array based on the search term parameter. However, when i run the code it only ever outputs the string at index 0 of the array. I want it to return the corresponding url in the array when a search is run.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a correct version of your program:

```
var arrayOfURL = [
                 "http://www.google.co.uk~Google is a search engine.",
                 "http://www.yahoo.co.uk~Yahoo is another search engine.",
                 "http://bing.com~Bing is a decision engine."
                 ];

function findURL(arrayOfURL,search)
{   
    var searchtoLower = search.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfURL.length; i++)
    {     
        var z = arrayOfURL[i].toLowerCase().split('~')[1]; 
        if (z.indexOf(searchtoLower) != -1)
            return arrayOfURL[i];
    }

     return "Nothing Found!";
}


findURL(arrayOfURL,"decision")
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to return URL based on the String after the ~?

Do the line

```
arrayOfURL[i].toLowerCase().split('~')[i];
```

seem weird to you? Imagine as i increases, eg. i = 4

```
 arrayOfURL[4].toLowerCase().split('~')[4];
```

Does that last [4] make sense?
I am guessing the reason it never got past the first element is because the code actually erroring out on that part.

I think what you want is (likewise for the return line, you'll want [0]

```
 arrayOfURL[i].toLowerCase().split('~')[1];
```

I would also take a look at

```
if (z >= searchtoLower)
```

what are you trying to compare there?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to return the url based on what is in the search parameter when the function is called. I'm not sure why [4], surely there is no index of 4 in the array? It still doesnt seem to be outputting the right url? Any other tips? thank you for your time!

Comment: [4] was an example to illustrate how the code will break down.

When you want to get the search term (the 2nd part of the String) you'll need [1] 
When you want to return the url (the first part of the String) you'll need [0]

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be in the second i param:

```
var z = arrayOfURL[i].toLowerCase().split('~')[i];
```

The string will be splitted into 2 parts (index 0, 1). Why did you select part **i**?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be doing

```
var terms = arrayOfURL[i].toLowerCase().split('~');

if(0 <= terms[1].indexOf(searchToLower))
           // ^    ^ 
           // |    |-- 0 <= indexOf method determines
           // |        if searchToLower is a substring of terms[1] 
           // |               
           // |-- term[1] gets the part after the first "~"
```

and

```
return terms[0]; //terms[0] is the part before the first "~"
```

I would also consider returning `null` or the empty string `""` in case of failure (instead of returning the arbritrary `"Nothing Found!"` message)

Comment: Hey thanks, but it still doesnt seem to returning the correct string from the array?